# Check if elapsed 5 minutes from PHP time stamp

Tags: php, timestamp

I've done some research but nothing useful come out.

I need to check if a DB time stamp is -5 minutes from current time stamp.
That time stamp is created with PHP `time()` function.

I tried with this without any luck:

```
$timestamp = "1451999400";

if(strtotime($timestamp) > strtotime("-5 minutes")) {
    echo "A";
} else {
    echo "B";
}
```

That code always returns "B".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure, that both the database and the PHP are using the same time zone. Then:

```
$timestamp = "1451999400";

if($timestamp > time() - 60*5) {
    echo "A";
} else {
    echo "B";
}
```

You don't need to convert the string to integer, because PHP will auto-convert it to a numeric type (possibly integer). (Because of the > operator)